# Panel Controls to Image

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to save the contents of a panel to an image which is displayed on a picturebox.  I am using the drawtobitmap method as shown below:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height)
    Panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, Panel1.ClientRectangle)
    PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = bmp

End Sub
```

The picturebox displays the image however the draw order is incorrect.

[image]

The box on the left is the panel with 3 buttons. The box on the right is the picturebox. Notice how the ordering differs. Does anyone have any suggestion of how to fix this so the ordering is the same as it appears on the panel?

Comment: I get the same result. Strange...

Comment: I am trying to at least find a creative work around even if this method itself fails.

Comment: OK, I posted a creative workaround :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jon B. You were correct to reverse the z order but I found this method below to do that for me instead which seems to work.  Thank you for your help! :)

```
For Each ctl As Control In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Control).OrderBy(Function(c) Me.Controls.GetChildIndex(c))
ctl.BringToFront()
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

I did this in c#, but you should be able to translate:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReverseControls(panel1);

    var bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
    panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, panel1.ClientRectangle);
    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = bmp;

    ReverseControls(panel1);
}

static void ReverseControls(Panel panel)
{
    var controls = panel.Controls.Cast<Control>().Reverse().ToArray();
    panel.Controls.Clear();
    panel.Controls.AddRange(controls);
}
```

Since it's drawing the controls in the reverse order, I just get a reversed list of controls and remove/readd them. Then un-reverse them after drawing the bitmap.

Comment: This doesn't seem to translate into VB .NET easily. 
var controls = panel.Controls.Cast<Control>().Reverse().ToArray();
is the line I have troubles with converting.

Comment: @Eric F: `Dim controls = panel.Controls.Cast(Of Control)().Reverse().ToArray()`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in VB.net

```
' flip all Controls to reverse order

For I As Int32 = MyPanel.Controls.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1

  MyPanel.Controls(I).SendToBack()

Next


'create Bitmap of Panel for Printer 

MyPanel.DrawToBitmap(bm, r)


' flip Controls again to restore original order on Screen 

For I As Int32 = MyPanel.Controls.Count- 1 To 0 Step -1

  MyPanel.Controls(I).SendToBack()

Next
```

Comment: You should format you answer properly using code blocks.  - From Review